# sql query update data between two union tables in different database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql

I have two database "db1" and "db2" with same table "table1". The two table have unique primary key "dv_no". My question is i want sql query to union two tables in two database [db1.table1 and db2.table1] the update specific data between two tables [db1.table1 and db2.table1].

Comment: To find *specific* answer you must add *specific* details, like data samples and desired output. If you have tried something, please, also share your code and problems you get with it.

Comment: MySQL?  SQL Server?  PostgreSQL?  Which RDBMS are you using?!

Answer (score 1):

if it's about t-sql you can try like this:

```
UPDATE DB1.dbo.TABLE1
SET tbl1.SOMECOLUMN = tbl2.SOMECOLUMN
FROM DB1.dbo.TABLE1 tbl1
INNER JOIN DB2.dbo.TABLE2 tbl2 ON tbl2.dv_no = tbl1.dv_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
select * from db1.table JOIN db2.table on 
db1.table.column = db2.table.column
```